# Can not set value dynamically in drop down using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one issue.I want to set value in drop down by `onchange` event using javascript/Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

```
<h1>drop down</h1>
<p>
    <select id="leaveCode" name="leaveCode" onChange="SetValue();">
        <option value="10">Annual Leave</option>
        <option value="11">Medical Leave</option>
        <option value="14">Long Service</option>
        <option value="17">Leave Without Pay</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <select id="leaveCode1" name="leaveCode">
        <option value="">select value</option>
        <option value="21">xyz</option>
        <option value="21">abc</option>
    </select>
</p>

function SetValue(){
  var value=document.getElementById('leaveCode').value;
  var name=document.getElementById('leaveCode').name;
  document.getElementById('leaveCode1').value=value;
  document.getElementById('leaveCode1').name=name;
}
```

Here my requirement is when user will select any value from 1st drop down list it will display also in second dropdown list in disable mode.Please help me.

Comment: See, the dropdown which is going to have the value of user interacting dropdown. Then the both should have the same values.

Comment: You can use this, http://jsfiddle.net/1vjoq4dn/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy : I checked but its not the solution.

Comment: What is your problem then? Can you brief a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following statement that will append and make select in leavecode1 dropdown.Use following statements in your js file

```
   jQuery('#leaveCode').change(function(){
        //get selected text from #leaveCode list
        text = jQuery("#leaveCode option:selected").text();
        //get selected value for selected text
        value = jQuery("#leaveCode option:selected").val();
//append new in #leavecode1 and make this option as selected option.
        jQuery("#leaveCode1").append("<option value=" + value + " selected>" + text + "</option>");



    });
```

You can check this using following link(updated)-http://jsfiddle.net/aecrcvt2/2/

Comment: It will add duplicate entries into the target dropdown. OP needs to explain a bit more about his/her problem.

Comment: var optionExists = (jQuery('#leaveCode1 option[value=' + value + ']').length > 0);
if optionExist return false then you need to add option in dropdown

Comment: I have updated link in answer.Please use that link to get answer of your query

Comment: @WisdmLabs : can you make it disable after appending the option.

Comment: jQuery("#leaveCode1").prop("disabled", true); use this statement to disable dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to Append the new value in your dropdownlist on change the leaveCode dropdownlist

```
  $("#leaveCode").change(function(){
$("#leaveCode1").append("<option value=" + $("#leaveCode").val() + ">" + $("#leaveCode option:selected").text() + "</option>")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function SetValue(obj) {
  var $this = $(obj);
  var val = $this.val();
  var txt = $('option:selected', $this).text();
  $('#leaveCode1').append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(txt));
  $('#leaveCode1').val(val).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
}
SetValue('#leaveCode');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>drop down</h1>
<p>
  <select id="leaveCode" name="leaveCode" onChange="SetValue(this);">
        <option value="10">Annual Leave</option>
        <option value="11">Medical Leave</option>
        <option value="14">Long Service</option>
        <option value="17">Leave Without Pay</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select id="leaveCode1" name="leaveCode">
        <option value="">select value</option>
        <option value="21">xyz</option>
        <option value="21">abc</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: @ pandeyvishal: I added your code but its throwning this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer you need:

```
$("#leaveCode").change(function(){
    var selectedOptionValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var selectedOptionText = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    var newOption = '<option value='+selectedOptionValue+' disabled>'+selectedOptionText+'</option>';
    $("#leaveCode1 option").last().after(newOption);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MR_Saberi/z0sbbuy6/)